# Getting CrossValidation split report at the end

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to convert my nested-CV pipeline into a format like the question of @Heavy Breathing--->
[Reference link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244907/how-to-get-hyper-parameters-in-nested-cross-validation)
His code suggests that:

```
outer_loop_accuracy_scores = []
inner_loop_won_params = []
inner_loop_accuracy_scores = []

# Looping through the outer loop, feeding each training set into a GSCV as the inner loop
for train_index,test_index in outer_kf.split(features,target):

    GSCV = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,param_grid=params,cv=inner_kf)

    # GSCV is looping through the training data to find the best parameters. This is the inner loop
    GSCV.fit(features[train_index],target[train_index])

    # The best hyper parameters from GSCV is now being tested on the unseen outer loop test data.
    pred = GSCV.predict(features[test_index])

    # Appending the "winning" hyper parameters and their associated accuracy score
    inner_loop_won_params.append(GSCV.best_params_)
    outer_loop_accuracy_scores.append(accuracy_score(target[test_index],pred))
    inner_loop_accuracy_scores.append(GSCV.best_score_)

for i in zip(inner_loop_won_params,outer_loop_accuracy_scores,inner_loop_accuracy_scores):
    print i

print 'Mean of outer loop accuracy score:',np.mean(outer_loop_accuracy_scores)
```

But i was using a nested-cv approach integrated with an onehotencoder inside a pipeline

```
params = {
        'max_depth':np.linspace(1, 32, 8, endpoint=True),
        'n_estimators': [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 200],
        'min_samples_split': np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5, endpoint=True),
        'min_samples_leaf':np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 5, endpoint=True)
        }
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 23)    
grid_search = GridSearchCV(rf, params, cv=3, verbose=10)

pipe = make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(sparse = True, handle_unknown='ignore'), grid_search)

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, random_state = 23, shuffle = False)

roc_auc = cross_val_score(pipe, df_x, df_y.values.ravel(), scoring = 'roc_auc', cv=cv)
accuracy = cross_val_score(pipe, df_x, df_y.values.ravel(), scoring = 'accuracy', cv=cv)


print("---%0.1f minutes---" %((timeit.default_timer()-start_time)/60))
print("roc_auc = {}, accuracy = {}".format(np.mean(roc_auc),np.mean(accuracy)))
```

Now, i want to transform it into the structure above, to get more detailed information about the split, outer split roc_auc and accuracy list for each split and also best_params and best_score list for gridsearchcv inside.

I used the code below but I am getting the error of
"None of [Int64Index([ 78,  79,  80,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,\n            ...\n            422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431],\n           dtype='int64', length=344)] are in the [columns]"

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 23)
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=True, handle_unknown = 'ignore')
outer_kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=False,random_state=1)
inner_kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=False,random_state=2)


params = {
        'max_depth':np.linspace(1, 32, 8, endpoint=True),
        'n_estimators': [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 200],
        'min_samples_split': np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5, endpoint=True),
        'min_samples_leaf':np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 5, endpoint=True)
        }

outer_loop_accuracy_scores = []
outer_loop_roc_auc_scores = []
inner_loop_won_params = []
inner_loop_accuracy_scores = []
for train_index,test_index in outer_kf.split(df_x,df_y.values.ravel()):

    GSCV = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf,param_grid=params,cv=inner_kf, verbose = 0)
    ohe_x = ohe.fit_transform(df_x[train_index]).to_array()
    ohe_x_test = ohe.transform(df_x[test_index]).to_array()

    # GSCV is looping through the training data to find the best parameters. This is the inner loop
    GSCV.fit(ohe_x,df_y[train_index])

    # The best hyper parameters from GSCV is now being tested on the unseen outer loop test data.
    pred = GSCV.predict(ohe_x_test)

    # Appending the "winning" hyper parameters and their associated accuracy score
    inner_loop_won_params.append(GSCV.best_params_)
    outer_loop_accuracy_scores.append(accuracy_score(df_y[test_index],pred))
    outer_loop_roc_auc_scores.append(roc_auc_score(df_y[test_index],pred))
    inner_loop_accuracy_scores.append(GSCV.best_score_)

for i in zip(inner_loop_won_params,outer_loop_roc_auc_scores,outer_loop_accuracy_scores,inner_loop_accuracy_scores):
    print(i)

print('Mean of outer loop accuracy score:',np.mean(outer_loop_accuracy_scores))
print('Mean of outer loop roc_auc score:',np.mean(outer_loop_roc_auc_scores))
print("---%0.1f minutes---" %((timeit.default_timer()-start_time)/60))
```

How can i integrate my structure with this line of code?
Can i use a pipeline inside for loop, or should i discard it?
How can i use use Onehotencoder? I am getting column error because of different feature values i think.

***Seems like problem was occuring because df_x was a DataFrame for me. I transformed it with 
df_x.values and df_y.values.ravel() and now it is working.

Im OK with error right now and it is working, but still i have to ask same questions about the logic and pipeline.